# Controlling text position

Tags: spacing

I'm writing a document and I want to put in a contact section with an e-mail address and a phone number. To signify that, I'm using `wasysym` and `bbding` for `\phone` and `\Envelope` symbols respectively. When I create the document, the e-mail address is not centered with the envelope; it's a little too low. How do I raise it?

EDIT: code:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
          \Envelope \ \href{mailto:my@mail.com}{my@mail.com} \\
          \phone \ 123 456 789
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It would be good if you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Then people see what you exactly doing and how to best change it to get the wanted result. You are talking about vertical centering, right? In general things can be raised using `\raisebox{<amount>}{<content>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document} 
          \Envelope \ \raisebox{.25em}{\href{mailto:my@mail.com}{my@mail.com}} \\
          \phone \ 123 456 789
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

I didn't notice Martin's comment already mentioning the answer. For this reason I'll make it CW.